# How to Compress and cache JS and CSS code in Prestashop

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6, prestashop-1.7

How can I combine and compress the CSS and JS code in Prestashop?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `CCC (Combine, Compress, and Cache)` feature of Prestashop.
In the Back office navigate to `Advanced Parameters -> Performance` and jump to the CCC section.
Toggle "Yes" for both the options `Smart cache for CSS` and `Smart cache for JavaScript` and Save.
On the front side inspect the page you can see all the CSS and JS code get merged and compressed.